# Is it possible to compile Cython modules without a Visual Studio license on Windows for commercial purposes? What are the alternatives?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cython, cythonize

This is regarding compiling Cython modules (or similar, built-in Python modules, e.g. PYD files) on Windows machines without using paid Microsoft Visual Studio licenses:

I tried many different solutions going from installing minGW, installing windows SDK, and nothing worked.

Is there any viable solution to compile Python3.9 code on Windows 10? Without having to pay for a Visual Studio license?

The simple solution is to install Visual Studio, but because it's for commercial use, I cannot use the community version, so I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: What do you mean by "compiling Python code"? Python is an interpreted language and by simply installing the Python interpreter you will be able to run scripts. If you're talking about compiling Python itself (e.g. Cython) then that is a different matter.

Comment: @furas thanks for help ><" I'm just not used to forums like this one. 
If there was any tutorial to do this I would not have post this. 
I just have no Idea where to start to solve my problem that's the reason why I posted this question here.

Comment: @JanWilamowski Yes indeed i'm talking about compiling Python itself whith the command cythonize

Comment: interpreted Python3.9 is already in C/C++ and it doesn't need to compile it with `Cython`. You can only use Cython to compile your Python script. But I would start at main page https://cython.org/ and links to [documentations](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

Comment: @furas thanks for helping me a bit ;) 

My purpose with cython is to speed up my code. I can launch it with the usual python way it works fine.
My problem is really to compile my code thanks to cythonize functionality of Cython on Windows environment. On Unix I do not have problem.

Comment: Do check the license for visual studio community. I don't believe it restricts commercial use (although it may limit the number of people in one company that can use it commercially)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to build for commercial purposes without licensing Microsoft Build Tools, you should look into using the compatible `clang-cl.exe` as well as the compatible linker `lld-link.exe` - Python PYD files generated with these LLVM tools I have found to work 100%.  Now the easiest way to install them is WITH MS Build Tools, but that's for convenience really. On my copy (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019) it's listed as the option: "C++ Clang Tools for Windows" and comes with Clang 12.0.0.  Although Microsoft can't just bundle the LLVM tools and change their license, which is the Apache License 2.0 - which does allow commercial use.  So I am not an attorney BUT I can pretty much be sure using only LLVM (Clang) bypasses any Microsoft license.

Now it's kind of a hack to do this but you can edit (on Windows) the `[Python]/Lib/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/_msvccompiler.py` now find and replace `link.exe` with `lld-link.exe` and comment out the `ldflags` option `'/LTCG'` as the LLVM linker will throw an error on that.  On some installs, the directory will actually be: `[Python]/Lib/distutils/_msvccompiler.py` so you'll have to examine your setup to decide.  I've had both on the exact same installation of Anaconda that threw me off because they randomly switched between using `setuptools` and `distutils`.  Now when you build using `clang-cl.exe` instead it will also default to `lld-link.exe` for the linker and you have bypassed any unfriendly licenses.  Note: I'm using Pythran which allows me to set `clang-cl` as the default; if your setup doesn't, you can also hack this same file `_msvccompiler.py` replacing `cl.exe` with `clang-cl.exe` and it will change the compiler.  Just as a note: compiling on Windows usually requires you to run the Visual Studio batch file `vsvarsall.bat x64` to setup the paths correctly, which on my PC is located at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\`

I didn't say it was super easy but in theory could install MS Build Tools 2019 and add the Clang Tools and do this with minimal effort.  I'm actually pretty surprised the entire Windows Python ecosystem hasn't already made `clang-cl` and `lld-link` the defaults for all builds, as they are compatible since Clang-12 at least...  I've seen entire NumPy and SciPy builds using it without any errors in their test suites...

Hope that is helpful.  I figured all this out making PYD files on Win10 with the Pythran package - which didn't have good documentation for Windows users.  I never really thought about the ramifications of the licenses until your question though.  I leave this "solution" up for myself as well.